# how to float two divs beside one div?

Tags: html

I want something below like structure in my webpage:

```
    +---------------+ +-----------+
    |               | |           |
    |               | |   Div-B   |
    |               | |Float:left |
    |               | |           |
    |     Div-A     | |           |
    |  Float: left  | +-----------+
    |               | +-----------+
    |               | |  Div-C    |
    |               | |<marquee>  |
    |               | |</marquee> |
    |               | +-----------+
    |               |
    +---------------+
```

But I can't creat Div-C like above style. If I give a different background color of Div-C, it extends to left border of Div-A. So I can't make white spaces between Div-A and Div-C. It is becoming like this:

```
+---------------+ +-----------+
|               | |           |
|               | |   Div-B   |
|               | |Float:left |
|               | |           |
|     Div-A     | |           |
|  Float: left  | +-----------+
|---------------|-+-----------+
|                    Div-C    |
| (Background color fills     |
|       this whole section    |
|---------------|-+-----------+
|               |
+---------------+
```

Also note that Div-C contains a marquee.
Please give me solution.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use something like this: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jpts/))

HTML:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="divA"></div>
    <div id="divB"></div>
    <div id="divC"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainContainer{ overflow:hidden; }
#divA{ float:left; width:60%; }
#divB{ float:right; width:30%; }
#divC{ float:right; width:30%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways possible.

1) You could use CSS Positioning. Cover all  your `divs` in a mother `div` then give the mother div a CSS `position:relative;` and a desired width and height...  then all the Children CSS `position: absolute;` then DivA could have CSS `left:0px;` then DivB could go for a CSS `right:0px; top:0px;` then DivC CSS `right:0px bottom:0px;`... give them their respective widths and Colors.
Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.kids{position:absolute;}
</style>

<div id="mainContainer" style="width:300px; height:500px; background:#ccc; position:relative;">
    <div class="kids" id="divA" style="width:60%; height:100%; top:0px; left:0px; background:orange;">A</div>
    <div class="kids" id="divB" style="width:60%; height:50%; top:0px; right:0px; background:green;">B</div>
    <div class="kids" id="divC" style="width:60%; height:50%; bottom:0px; right:0px; background:red;">C</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgkWL/

2) Create a `<table>` with 1 full column and 2 half columns. Place the `divs` in respective columns.

```
<div id="aNewWrapper"  style="width:300px; height:500px;">
  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" rowspan="2" height="500"><div  id="divA" style="width:100%; height:100%;  background:orange;">A</div></td>

      <td width="50%" height="250"><div  id="divB" style="width:100%; height:100%; background:green;">B</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="250"><div id="divC" style="width:100%; height:100%; background:red;">C</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tWCBP/